# I need help running a program called NeoniteV2-2.7.5

Tags: node.js, npm

Need help fixing a install.bat it causes this error and says
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\tjmye\Desktop/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\tjmye\Desktop\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\tjmye\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-02-09T19_41_59_045Z-debug-0.log

C:\Users\tjmye\Desktop>

Comment: and when i go to C:\Users\tjmye\AppData\Local there is no folders

Comment: See https://github.com/NeoniteDev/NeoniteV2 and https://www.neonitedev.live/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.